# Turn off scaling for PDF embedded in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I need to embed a PDF in an HTML page and I need the PDF to *not* scale to fit its bounds. So, if the PDF `<object>` tag is 900px wide, but the document is 1200px wide, I want the document to display at its original size and to have horizontal scrolling. I'm currently using the following, which does not work (it scales the PDF down to fit the CSS width of the `<object>` tag):

```
<object id="pdf" width="100%" height="100%" data="http://urlto.mypdf.com/test-2.pdf?#zoom=100" type="application/pdf">
    <param name="src" value="http://urlto.mypdf.com/test-2.pdf?#zoom=100" />
    <param name="zoom" value="100%" />
    <param name="type" value="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

How can I get the PDF to stop scaling? I'd be happy to use a JavaScript solution, if one exists that will work within my requirements. I cannot, however, use a Flash solution because this must work on mobile devices.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this falls into plugin realm and browsers themselves don't necessarily control that.

Comment: You can add display settings to the PDF that ask the PDF viewer to not scale.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `pdf.setZoom` for that. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306485/how-to-view-particular-page-of-an-pdf-using-html-in-browser/18306632#18306632) of mine for more info.